# React warning Maximum update depth exceeded: firebase-react-hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Currently, I'm trying to check if the user is logged in for my home page and display some different components depending on the log-in status.

However, i'm getting this warning :

> “Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.”

The following is my code in **Appshell.js**

```
import React from "react";
import TopRight from "./TopRight";
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import BootstrapButton from "./BootstrapButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDocumentData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import SignOut from "./SignOut";

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

function AppShell() {
  ###The following line of code is causing the error###

  const [currentUser] = useAuthState(firebase.auth());

  #####################################################

  const userRef = firestore.collection("Users").doc(currentUser?.uid);
  const [user] = useDocumentData(userRef);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        {currentUser ? <SignOut /> : <TopRight />}
      </div>
      <AppBar elevation={0} position="static" style={{ background: "#EDEDED" }}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Link to="/">
            <BootstrapButton color="default">Home</BootstrapButton>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/opportunities">
            <BootstrapButton color="default">Opportunities</BootstrapButton>
          </Link>
          {user?.Class === "recruiter" ? (
            <Link to="/myposts">
              <BootstrapButton color="default">My Posts</BootstrapButton>
            </Link>
          ) : (
            <Link to="/organisations">
              <BootstrapButton color="default">Organisations</BootstrapButton>
            </Link>
          )}

          <Link to="/about">
            <BootstrapButton color="default">About</BootstrapButton>
          </Link>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </>
  );
}

export default AppShell;
```

I have tried placing the line of code `const [currentUser] = useAuthState(firebase.auth());` inside a useEffect hook to only update when page is rendered but apparently its not allowed. Hence, any suggestion to get rid of this error is much appreciated, thanks!